# How to call a function within innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

This is InnerHTML String
I'm calling a function within innerHTML but it is not considered as a function call Instead it simply print the code as it is if I use script tag.

```
addCard()
  {
    if(this.cardItem.length == 0)
    {
      this.dataOrder = 0;
      this.temp = "<html><div class='col-md-4' id='replicateCard'><div class='card custom-card'><img class='card-img-top card-image' src='../../assets/images/user.png' alt='Card image cap'><a class='close' onclick='showAlert()'>×</a><div class='card-body card-body-custom'><br><p class='card-title'>"+this.dataTitle+"</p><p class='card-text'>"+this.dataDesc+"</p><p class='card-text'>"+this.dataDesc+"</p><p class='card-text'>"+this.dataOrder+"</p></div></div></div></html>";
      this.cardItem.splice(this.dataOrder, 0, this.temp);
    }
}
```

This is my function to call:

```
 showAlert()
  {
    alert("I'm working");
  }
```

Comment: there is no `innerHTML` ... there is a string in `temp`

Comment: problem is scoping.... onclick will fire on window

Comment: Could you implement this example?

    `document.getElementById("html").innerHTML = "<p>Your message <a 
    href='javascript:functionName();'>click for script</a></p>"`

Comment: where and how are you trying to add `this.temp` to DOM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would not recommend doing this way. 
For your case you'll need to make sure second function is in the global scope.

If not you can simply write it as

```
window.showAlert = function(){ alert("your message") }
```

Or you can bind the events dynamically to the new dom elements